# use one fragment with different data in viewPager doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

this is my ViewPager

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }
        void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

and in main activity,

```
public void setupViewPager() {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(NowPlayingFragment.newInstance(0), getString(R.string.now_playing));
    adapter.addFragment(NowPlayingFragment.newInstance(1), getString(R.string.up_coming));
    adapter.addFragment(NowPlayingFragment.newInstance(2), getString(R.string.popular));
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is my fragment.

```
public static NowPlayingFragment newInstance(int titleId){
    NowPlayingFragment fragment = new NowPlayingFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title_flag", titleId);
    NowPlayingFragment.titleId = titleId;
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    args = savedInstanceState;
    mContext = getContext();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_now_playing, container, false);
    mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    Map<String, String> queryString;
    queryString = ApiUtils.getQueryStrings(mContext);
    Uri uri;
    int titleId1 = 0;
    if (args != null) {
         titleId1 = args.getInt("title_flag");
    }
    Log.d("tag", "titleId = " + titleId1);
    switch (titleId1){
        case 0:
            uri = ApiUtils.getNowPlayingUri(mContext, queryString);
            break;
        case 1:
            uri = ApiUtils.getUpcomingUri(mContext, queryString);
            break;
        case 2:
            uri = ApiUtils.getPopularUri(mContext, queryString);
            break;
        default:
            uri = ApiUtils.getNowPlayingUri(mContext, queryString);
            break;
    }

    new loadDiscoverList(getContext()).execute(uri);

    return view;
}
```

I try to list three different movie list (now playing, upcoming, popular).
But it only shows now playing list on all three pages.

It seems like passing data from main activity to fragment is not working property, or store fragment argument problem. But I can't find what cause this issue and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try using addOnPageChangeListener of viewpager to load the data when fragment changes

Comment: @MarkKeen I change it saveInstanceState to getArguments(). now it shows now Playing and popular but not showing upcoming. I mean it shows when app start but as soon when swipt, it overlay with popular list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here `args = savedInstanceState;` it should be `args = getArguments();` - at present only your default list in your switch statement is honoured. `SavedInstanceState` is for configuration changes, you want the Fragment arguments you added with the static Fragment generator method.

Comment: I change it saveInstanceState to getArguments(). now it shows now Playing and popular but not showing upcoming. I mean it shows when app start but as soon when swipt, it overlay with popular list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have make a cache for fragment like:
    private final List mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
ViewPager already do it for you.
Try to return the corresponding new instances of fragments inside the method getItem() in your adapter.

Comment: I modified getItem() as return NowPlayingFragment.newInstance(position).
and first time it shows good. but as soon as when I scroll down and come back up. it replace with popular.